# How to set environment via `ng serve` in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

I am trying to update my Angular 5.2 app to Angular 6. I successfully followed instructions in the Angular update guide (including the update of `angular-cli` to v6), and now I am trying to serve the app via

```
ng serve --env=local
```

But this gives me error:

> Unknown option: '--env'

I use multiple environments (`dev/local/prod`), and this is the way it was working in Angular 5.2. How can I set the environment now in Angular 6?

Comment: its v6, you update `angular-cli` alongside with the whole app, so i thought its obvious :]

Comment: Very helpful, Martin. Thanks for sharing your insight. In fact it isn't in the least obvious.

Answer (score 464, accepted):

You need to use the new `configuration` option (this works for `ng build` and `ng serve` as well)

```
ng serve --configuration=local
```

or

```
ng serve -c local
```

If you look at your `angular.json` file, you'll see that you have finer control over settings for each configuration (aot, optimizer, environment files,...)

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": true,
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can get more info [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments) for managing environment specific configurations.

As pointed in the other response below, if you need to add a new 'environment', you need to add a new configuration to the **build** task and, depending on your needs, to the **serve** and **test** tasks as well.

**Adding a new environment**

**Edit**:
To make it clear, file replacements must be specified in the `build` section. So if you want to use `ng serve` with a specific `environment` file (say **dev2**), you first need to modify the `build` section to add a new **dev2** configuration

```
"build": {
   "configurations": {
        "dev2": {

          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev2.ts"
            }
            /* You can add all other options here, such as aot, optimization, ... */
          ],
          "serviceWorker": true
        },
```

Then modify your `serve` section to add a new configuration as well, pointing to the **dev2** `build` configuration you just declared

```
"serve":
      "configurations": {
        "dev2": {
          "browserTarget": "projectName:build:dev2"
        }
```

Then you can use `ng serve -c dev2`, which will use the dev2 config file

Comment: do you know if it's possible to also add base-href in the configurations?



or just in ng build --c staging --base-href = /yyy/

Comment: @EduardoTolino: Yes you can, there is a `baseHref` option

Comment: Where could I specify the remote debugging port for the dev environment ? So as to debug with `VSCode`. In `Angular 6` of course. So that the `ng serve` command includes the remote debugger port when launching the `Chrome` browser.

Comment: info link updated: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Comment: ng serve -c local take time to compile the application comparing to "ng serve"

Comment: ng serve in angular-cli 6 don't work with file replacement https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11540#issuecomment-406030775

Comment: Be sure that in your component, you import
`import { environment } from './../environments/environment';` instead of
`import { environment } from './../environments/environment.prod'`

The "intelligent" code help imported the latter for me.

Comment: The `"serve"` part saved my day, thank you.
I didn't noticed that migrating environments only to the `"build"` section is not enough.

Comment: Is anyone here aware how to enable debugging while working with multiple environments ? I am unable to debug while using QA Environment, check this out  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045274/typescript-debugger-statement-does-not-work-while-working-with-qa-environme/56045408#56045408

Comment: Thanks for this, I always wanted to have custom configurations on serve, but just now I had the time to do some research and found this! :)

Answer (score 64):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174679/1484847) answer seems good.
however, it lead me towards an error as it resulted with
 `Configuration 'xyz' could not be found in project ...`
error in build.
It is requierd not only to updated **build** configurations, but also **serve**
 ones.

So just to leave no confusions:

1. `--env` is not supported in `angular 6`
2. `--env` got changed into `--configuration` || `-c` (and is now more powerful)
3. to manage various envs, in addition to adding new environment file, it is now required to do some changes in `angular.json` file:

   - add new configuration in the **build** `{ ... "build": "configurations": ...` property
   - new *build configuration* may contain only `fileReplacements` part, (but more options are available)
   - add new configuration in the **serve** `{ ... "serve": "configurations": ...` property
   - new *serve configuration* shall contain of `browserTarget="your-project-name:build:staging"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes a nice addition to the one above. Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

Angular no longer supports --env instead you have to use

```
ng serve -c dev
```

for development environment and,

```
ng serve -c prod
```

for production.

NOTE: `-c` or `--configuration`

Comment: This was asked & answered year ago, also your answer is wrong, its `-c` (with single dash) or `--configuration` (with double dashes).

Comment: how can we do same for SSR version ?

Answer (score 12):

You can try: `ng serve --configuration=dev/prod`

To build use: `ng build --prod --configuration=dev`

Hope you are using a different kind of environment.

Comment: ng serve --configuration=dev/prod command takes time comparing to ng serve why?

Comment: ng serve --configuration=prod takes more time then ng serve --configuration=prod because of file minimization and due to production ready code.

Comment: ok if i use "ng serve --configuration=dev" command means its also taking more time

Comment: No, it shouldn't take more time. The prod environment has extra steps to minify, uglify and optimize the code for production. The other environments should take the normal time, unless you explicitly activate these extra steps.

Answer (score 9):

For Angular 2 - 5 refer the article [Multiple Environment in angular](https://medium.com/@onlyyprasanth/how-to-manage-multiple-environments-with-angular-cli-angular-2-to-5-aa68d557fa77)

For Angular 6 use `ng serve --configuration=dev`

> Note: Refer the same article for angular 6 as well. But wherever you find `--env` instead use `--configuration`. That's works well for angular 6.

Answer (score 4):

You can use command `ng serve -c dev` for development environment
                    `ng serve -c prod` for production environment

while building also same applies. You can use `ng build -c dev` for dev build

Answer (score 2):

Use this command for Angular 6 to build

```
ng build --prod --configuration=dev
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on Angular 12

step 1:

```
"serve":
  "configurations": {
    "staging": {
      "browserTarget": "projectName:build:staging"
    }
```

Step 2:
npx ng run myapp:serve --configuration=staging