# How to specify environment via `ng build` in Angular 6 app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

In Angular 5,
we could generate build for different environments using

```
ng build --prod --env=uat
```

After migration to Angular 6 the above command throws error

```
Unknown option: '--env'
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One needs to use the configuration option

```
ng build --prod --configuration=uat
```

or

```
ng build --prod -c uat
```

More information [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/application-environments.md)

Also for ng serve same option as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174679/470347)

Comment: Why in the bloody H    would thery remove that information from `ng build --help` . Thanks for the anser @nehal

Comment: angular7 its `ng build --prod --aot`

Comment: In at least Angular 8 there is no reason to specify both `--prod` and `--configuration`.  `--configuration` overrides `--prod`.  [Source](https://angular.io/cli/build)

Comment: `ng build --prod --configuration=uat` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 10):

I have tested in an Angular 6 Project.

`ng build --prod --configuration=uat` doesn't seem to work as it only picks uat configuration when you run this command and ignores `--prod` flag and doesn't apply any optimization such as aot, minification and upglification etc.

Running `ng build --prod --configuration=uat` has the effect as same as only running `ng build --configuration=uat`. In order to apply any other configuration options we need to add them explicitly in the uat build options in angular.json

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        },
        "uat": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use:

```
ng build --configuration=uat
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use

ng build ---prod

Comment: OP wants to set the build for a particular environment, so someway of specifying that is required. the --prod is primary a "release" build which does bundling and similar stuff, but environment  itself can have configurations to be put in

Answer (score 0):

```
Prod: ng build --prod
Qa: ng build --configuration=qa

angular.json
"production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
},
"qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ]
}

PROD:
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api : 'https://example.com'
}

QA:
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    api : 'https://example-Qa.com'
}

dev environment
export const environment = {
    production:false,
    api : 'https://example-dev.com'
}
```