# How to add/set environment Angular 6 angular.json file

Tags: angular, angular6

How do I specify the environment to use in Angular 6+? The `.angular-cli.json` file seems to have changed to `angular.json` from previous versions and with it the structure of the `json` within.

How/where in this file do I specify the environments to use?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174584/how-to-set-environment-via-ng-serve-in-angular-6/50174679#50174679 and here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/application-environments.md

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Open angular.json file. we can see the configurations by default it will be shown for production add code snippet for your respective environments. add environment.dev.ts file in environment for dev, add environment.qa.ts for qa. Name as you prefered.
use

```
 ng serve --configuration=environment_name
```

environment_name - (dev,qa,prod) same process can be followed for ng build

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        },
        "dev": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": true,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        },
        "qa": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
```

Comment: This is the information I was looking for! The default angular.json file only includes production config so I had no idea how to setup other environments such as dev.

Comment: and also how to set the environment in angular-cli

Comment: You can use ng build --configuration=environment_name for building.
For running using ng serve add code snippet in serve property of angular.json file
"serve": {
          .....
        "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "AppName:build:production"
            },
            "environment_name": {
              "browserTarget": "AppName:build:environment_name"
            },
         }
Then use ng-serve --configuration=environment_name

Comment: For dev in Angular 12, for building you've to use the command: "ng build -c development" , for running, if by default "ng serve" is not development then try: "ng serve -c development". For other environment, you've add environment file and mention in angluar.json for "configurations" and "serve", just follow the "production" as example and then in cli  to run "ng serve -c <your environment file name>" and for building using "ng build-c <your environment file name>"

Answer (score 19):

I tried the answer to add a new configuration 'test' in my Angular 6 app, then ran

```
ng serve --configuration=test
```

And got an error saying 'Configuration 'test' could not be found in project'. 
Look down in angular.json file and there's another section under "build" which is called "serve". The new configuration needs to be added to the configuration section under "serve" also to get ng serve to work with it:

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
        },
        "test": {
          "browserTarget": "my-app:build:test"
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: it's for ng build --configuration=qa, not serve.

Comment: @DanielNetzer in order to get serve to run like mentioned in the answer, I still need to add this part.

Answer (score 2):

In order to set up the environments correctly, we need to let Angular know by adding these to the configuration file `angular.json`. We will do this by extending the configurations object:

```
... // angular.json
configurations": {
    "production" {...} // leave as it is,
    "dev": {
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And then, will have to update the serve object:

```
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "<appname>:build"
    },
    "configurations": {
        "production": ... // leave as it is
        "dev": {
            "browserTarget": "<appname>:build:dev"
        }
    }
},
```

create one more environment file with `environment.dev.ts` under the `src/environment/` directory

and run the below command

```
ng serve -c=dev
```

you can also create one command to run this environment separately by adding code below in package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "start:dev": "ng serve -c=dev --port=4000"
   }
}
```

here we go

```
npm run start:dev
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure I hope this will help others and save their time :)

Comment: @Hidayt Rahman Same like need for json file replace, can you please give some sample

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in angular.json to specify which file to use in dev and prod and as usual, you import environment.ts in your project to get what you need.

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
```