# Environment change unexpectedly

Tags: angular

In angular 6.0 project, Whenever I rerunning the application the current environment was changed and pointing to the other environment

**For example**

In my project I have maintain 3 environment ( dev, test, prod ).when using the command
**ng serve -e dev** it pointing to the dev instance. But rerunning the application,It automatically pointed to prod instance.

Comment: did you try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50344705/6706381

Comment: Try ng serve --c=dev or ng build --c=production