# Angular `ng serve --prod` is the same as `ng serve -c production`?

Tags: angular-cli, production-environment

I am using Angular 7 and I wonder if

```
ng serve --prod
```

is the same as

```
ng serve -c production
```

Can't find that in the documentation so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174584/how-to-set-environment-via-ng-serve-in-angular-6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is some documentation on it here: https://angular.io/cli/build

It says that `-c` is the alias for `--configuration`

> A named build target, as specified in the "configurations" section of
>   angular.json. Each named target is accompanied by a configuration of
>   option defaults for that target.
>
> Aliases: -c

The documentation for `--prod` says:

> When true, sets the build configuration to the production target. All builds make use of bundling and limited tree-shaking. A production
>   build also runs limited dead code elimination.

So it sounds to me like the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

***In Angular 16***, both are not the same.

```
ng serve --prod
```

The above command throws error -

> Error: Unknown argument: prod

However, `ng serve -c production` works as expected with the following output.

> Warning: 'outputHashing' option is disabled when using the dev-server.
> **************************************************************************************** This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular
> applications locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.
>
> DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
> **************************************************************************************** ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

You can verify by checking the size of the chunk files. It should be significantly less than the dev build.