# How to set separate dev and release proxy / backend api urls?

Tags: angular, rest, url, proxy, web-deployment

What I want to achieve is when I use the Angular / C# Web Api project in localhost and developing it I use this url in the Angular app:

http://localhost:5000/api/something

But this isn't working in deployment. I want to use the "/something" or something like that when the frontend and the backend is together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set environment via \`ng serve\` in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174584/how-to-set-environment-via-ng-serve-in-angular-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `src` directory create your environments:

[image]

`export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/api/something',
};`

Angular command line tool knows which file to use for each environment.

Then import it:

`import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';`

And now use them in my classes as any other object:

`apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;`

[Read more on the web](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be)