# Can I pass a variable to environment.ts on ng serve?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm regularly running a project locally with two different configurations. One with stubbed data, one connected to the Spring Boot backend. I can switch between these modes with the below logic by making `connectToBackend=true`.

```js
// Angular 11, src/environments/environment.ts

import processStubs from '[REDACTED]';
import processBackend from '[REDACTED]';
import { Launcher } from '[REDACTED]';

let connectToBackend = false;

let processLocal;
if (connectToBackend) {
  processLocal = processBackend;
} else {
  processLocal = processStubs;
}

export const environment = {
  process: processLocal,
  launcher: Launcher,
  production: false,
  backendConnection: connectToBackend,
};
```

How can I make `connectToBackend` a dynamic variable that is set by the command line when serving the project? For example:

```
ng serve --connectToBackend=true
```

Comment: Why not just make it _two environments_?

Comment: environment.prod.ts is already in use. I think you can add to the list of custom environments in the angular.json, but I was not able to get that to work with 'ng serve --...'.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you did, but if you follow the guidance at e.g. https://angular.io/guide/build that should work. If not, give a [mre]. It's certainly going to be easier than trying to add custom arguments.

Comment: You can create other environments, check: https://itnext.io/multi-environment-setup-for-your-angular-app-a211d72f1ff1 https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#alternate-build-configurations

Comment: Thank you both and Arutsudar for the answer below. The multi-environments solution is the way to go and works fine for ng serve now. I was missing the config under "serve" in angular.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ng serve](https://angular.io/cli/serve) command accepts the parameter `configuration`.

You can have multiple environments in angular *(as also suggested by others in comments)*.

In `angular.json` you can mention a new environment configuration that can overwrite the default environment file. (Referred from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174679/5384491))

```
"build": {
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      // ...
    },
    "demo": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.demo.ts"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

"serve": {
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      // ...
    },
    "demo": {
      "browserTarget": "PROJECTNAME:build:demo"
    }
  }
}
```

Create a new file `src/environments/environment.demo.ts` to store the value of `backendConnection` variable (along with other necessary variables)

```
export const environment = {
  process,
  launcher: Launcher,
  production: false,
  backendConnection: true
};
```

For running the new environment, you can use a command like this
`ng serve -c=demo`.